# Jersey Jax-rs got Container Exception

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

Iam new in Jax-Rs.I trying the post the data from html to Webresource method.In the runtime i got exception i.e.,

```
exception 

javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: Exception injecting parameters to Web resource method
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:310)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:314)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:239)


root cause 

com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: Exception injecting parameters to Web resource method
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.FormDispatchProvider$FormParamInInvoker.getParams(FormDispatchProvider.java:103)


root cause 


java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
    com.sun.jersey.core.util.MultivaluedMapImpl.getFirst(MultivaluedMapImpl.java:81)
    com.sun.jersey.core.util.MultivaluedMapImpl.getFirst(MultivaluedMapImpl.java:53)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.parameter.multivalued.StringExtractor.extract(StringExtractor.java:61)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.FormDispatchProvider$FormParamInjectable.getValue(FormDispatchProvider.java:233)
```

I mentioned the below Html Page & Web Resource Method:-

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Test Jax-RS Object</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="services/fruitstore/loadObject1" method="POST" >
<table>
<tr>
    <td>ID:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="id"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Name:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="submit" Value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

WebResource Method:-

```
@POST
@Path("loadObject1")
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

public void loadObject1(@FormParam("id") String id,@FormParam("name") String name){
    System.out.println("====================");
    System.out.println("Fruit ID"+id+" Name"+name);

}
```

Please help me?

Comment: will you get multiple values for `id` and `name` ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the problem is with the `@Path` - you should have your class annotated, not the method. The following should work:

```
package net.asteasolutions.imagenation.boundary;

import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("loadObject1")
public class TestService {

    @POST
    public void loadObject1(
        @FormParam("id") String id,
        @FormParam("name") String name
    ) {
        System.out.println("====================");
        System.out.println("Fruit ID"+id+" Name"+name);
    }
}
```

Note that you don't need to use "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" explicitly, Jersey will figure it out automatically. :-)